# Python twitter API error for Twitter class

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am trying to use the python twitter API but it can't find the Twitter class.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter

For instance I do the following without any errors:

```
 from twitter import *
```

But when I do:

```
 >>> t = Twitter(auth)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'Twitter' is not defined
```

What am I missing? Is there a different python twitter library I need to install?

Comment: Did you create a file called twitter.py in the same location you are trying to perform that import?

Comment: No, I am just running from the python REPL

Comment: I did see that other answer on SO btw

Comment: Is your `from twitter import *` being performed in the same REPL session as your `t = Twitter(auth)` command?

Comment: Yes, I just typed those lines one after another. auth is set to OAuth1(..) in a separate line.

Comment: Did you install it in a virtualenv and you happen to *not* be in that virtualenv when trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tweepy library, easy to use. Take a look at http://www.tweepy.org/

Here is a code example:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('','')

auth.set_access_token('', '')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.followers_ids()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print len(public_tweets)
```